# How to hide or provide restriction to NiFi workflow?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have NiFi workflow and we are thinking when our application goes to production how we can protect our workflow? What are the best practices? solutions? etc.

Kindly share your experience.

Thanks and Regards,
Yeshwant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many resources answering this question. The Apache NiFi Administration Guide has sections on configuring [HTTPS/TLS](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#security_configuration), user authentication using [client certificates](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#user_authentication), [LDAP](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#ldap_login_identity_provider), [Kerberos](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#kerberos_login_identity_provider), etc., applying fine-grained resource authorization via [internal policy configuration](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#authorizer-configuration), and [integrating with LDAP users/groups](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#ldapusergroupprovider).

There are also many independent and community-generated guides to integrating policy administration with Apache Ranger ([Bryan Bende's blog](https://bryanbende.com/development/2016/08/22/apache-nifi-1.0.0-using-the-apache-ranger-authorizer), [instructions](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.1.2/bk_security/content/ch05s04.html)), [applying policy rules](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.1.2/bk_user-guide/content/UI-with-multi-tenant-authorization.html), and [configuring multi-tenant authorization](https://bryanbende.com/development/2016/08/17/apache-nifi-1-0-0-authorization-and-multi-tenancy), etc.